# Access to the database file is not allowed SeCreateFile Error

Tags: sql-server-ce, manifest, installshield

I knw there are some answers about this error, But none of them working for me.
I used Installshield to create a setup package for my C# application. it works fine on my pc.But when I install in on end-user machine, i get this error:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1884,File name = C:\Program Files (x86)\Faranegah\DB\MC.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

all of the solution I've found is about to set manifest file configuration like this:

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false
```

Or edit connection string as this:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mc.sdf
```

But my setting are already like that and I still get that error unless i run the application by right click and select "Run as administrator..". 
So plz before you announce it as duplicate question, make sure you've found the right solution in other questions.
Thanx in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after taking a couple of hours trying I got the solution.

The problem was that I set that manifest setting to my installshield. The thing i forgot was that I had to create a manifest file for my own application too!

So i create one for my application and it worked!

Comment: For me the solution was to set the 'write' property to true to the database file (*.sdf) on the server.